# Android Gingerbread Image won't boot on Raspberry Pi, netd/zygote issue

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've downloaded an image of Gingerbread that is linked to in [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=12729). I ran the command `dd if=Gingerbread.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M` to copy the image to an SD card.

The first time I booted the Pi it worked OK, but I couldn't unlock the screen as I had no mouse attached. Then I powered off, plugged in a USB mouse, and powered on again. This time the Pi didn't boot, it seems to go into a loop saying something along the lines of:

```
starting zygote
starting process /system/bin/zygote PID 101
killing unknown process 101
starting netd
starting process /system/bin/netd PID 111
killing unknown process 111
```

That's not the exact output as I can't copy and paste and the screen has now died. The PID number is increased by 10 everytime and it seems to go into an infinite loop.

Even if I unplug the mouse and reboot I still get this error. Is there anything I can do to get rid of it?